# Cannot find GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I have the latest version of Stanford CoreNLP (3.8) installed, and I have been playing around with the package. I am now attempting to use SPIED, but I am getting an error.

Even if I followed through the instructions, when I run the command I get an error message saying it cannot find the main class GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.

Following is the command I ran:
***java -cp classpath edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass -props pl.properties***

And I ran this at the ***stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09*** directory.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

For people experiencing the same situation, make sure you create lib folder and move all the jar files to it before running this.

Refer to: https://github.com/sonalgupta/SPIED-viz/blob/master/setupWithCoreNLP.sh